# C Find a subset of strings from a list

Tags: c, search

I have a list of 1M entries and I want to exclude a subset of 20,000 of these entries (the two lists are in different order by have the same key (string)). Can anyone suggest a quick search algorithm in C to do this?

I dont want to have to read each of the 20K IDs and look through the list of 1M every time. Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use is a hash set. A hash set is a special case of a hash table that basically records if an element exists in the set or not, in constant time. So, what you would do is insert your 20k IDs into the hash set, and then run through the 1 million strings and see if they exist in the hash set.

For your reference, here's an implementation of a hash set in C: https://github.com/avsej/hashset.c

Your running time would be O(n), since for each check for the 1M strings, it would be constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Sort both lists first. Then you can traverse them together, advancing the pointer in the list that is behind the pointer in the other.

Do you have to use C? This sounds like a job for Perl.

Comment: I have to use C as the rest of the analysis needs to be done in C and perl would be too slow for the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Put the 20,000 keys to be included in a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) before you start searching the list. Then for each item's key in the list, if that key is found in the hash table, exclude the item from the list.